# My application runs as sudo, how do I make it git pull using my user's credentials?

Tags: linux, git, sudo

I run my application as sudo but I need it to use a git pull based on the information in `~/.gitconfig` and `~/.netrc` files my current user has. How do I do this without putting my credentials in the root user account.

Comment: Did you find anything interesting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842719/3569208)?

Comment: What's "my application" composed of? Is it a script, an executable the source of which you have full control over, or a 3rd party application you can't modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [sudo man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), changing the `HOME` environment variable may be the default behavior, but it doesn't have to be. If the `HOME` environment variable is not updated, you can probably just not change anything and it will work. Check the [sudoers man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) for more information about `sudo` policies, including updating the `HOME` environment variable.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux-c) covers finding a user's home directory programmatically. You could use this approach (obviously *not* using `HOME` environment variable approach, if that gets changed by `sudo`). Note that `getuid` returns the "real" UID of the calling process, which will be the user you want (`geteuid` gets the *effective* UID instead, which in your case would be root). You can then find the user's configuration and credential files, and use them, or possibly just (temporarily or otherwise) edit your process' `HOME` environment variable before calling `git` functions.

You could also just have your program take a path to a `git` configuration and/or credential file as a parameter. Users would need to supply these manually, but you could then pass them down to `git` in your program.

**Important caveat: All of these suggestions operate on the assumption that the user can be trusted (that is, if the user can call sudo, they are allowed to completely take over the system).**

If your program uses a custom `sudo` policy that allows it to be called by untrusted users (or is setuid root itself and executable by untrusted users), then you need to be much more careful. For example, an untrusted user that wanted to access something using another user's `git` credentials might create a symlink to the target user's configuration / credential file(s), then use your program (or might pass the other user's profile, if you went with the command line argument approach). The best way to mitigate this threat, aside from "don't run your program as root", is to use `seteuid(getuid())` to temporarily lower your effective UID to your user's real UID, which means attempting to access other users' files will result in denied access. You can restore the effective UID afterward, if needed.